# Unknow error when mounting /dev/sdb1

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I tried `sudo apt install --reinstall ntfs-3g` then the `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1`, and get this:

```
Mounting volume... Incomplete multi-sector transfer: magic: 0x58444e49  size: 4096  usa_ofs: 40  usa_count: 6  data: 37069  usn: 37068: Input/output error
Corrupt index block signature: vcn 0 inode 5
Failed to open $Secure: No such file or directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Incomplete multi-sector transfer: magic: 0x58444e49  size: 4096  usa_ofs: 40  usa_count: 6  data: 37069  usn: 37068: Input/output error
Corrupt index block signature: vcn 0 inode 5
Failed to open $Secure: No such file or directory
Remount failed: No such file or directory
```

And the problem persist

Comment: You're sure this is an NTFS partition yes?  If so, then you're getting `Input/output error` errors, which suggests hardware is going bad - especially since it's the same sector on the drive that's triggering.  `ntfsfix` can't fix a broken/dying hard drive, I would back up what data you can from this drive and then expect to replace it and restore your data.

Comment: If you dual-boot with Windows, run `chkdsk /f D:` and/or `chkdsk /r D:` from an admin console. Change the drive letter appropriately. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema sorry I dont have a dual-boot, I just have access to my ubuntu laptop, there is a way a can do this from there?

Comment: @EMMANUELBRANDOQUILLAROMERO Is this an internal or external drive?

Comment: @heynnema external drive, but even that i dont have a windows machine can I use

Comment: @EMMANUELBRANDOQUILLAROMERO I don't know how to help you.

Comment: If not using Windows, best not to use NTFS as it requires defrag & chkdsk which can only be run from Windows. You can download a Windows installer with repair console or Windows repair tool ISO. But that is a Windows question and we support Ubuntu. You should check drive's Smart status and convert partition to ext4 & restore data from your normal backup.

Comment: @oldfred well I can't able to use the Smart status, its greyend on the menu options for that device. From everyone recomendations i guess i have to find the way to access a windows machine and try from there

Answer (score 0):

The devices drops "input/output error".
Give it a look with this [package](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/gnome-disk-utility)

When it installed, run gnome-disks from console and inside launched app you could select the device and from menu check S.M.A.R.T. Status indicators.

Comment: I cant use the S.T.A.R.T options, its greyed on the options menu for that device

Comment: Most external drives don't support SMART